# NVPARSER: HEVC: Seeking is not performed on IRAP picture

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, rtsp, gstreamer-1.0

I am trying to use Gstreamer to run my rtsp stream and I am getting this error
NVPARSER: HEVC: Seeking is not performed on IRAP picture. Can someone explain to me why this error might be occurring. I am running the following command in terminal.

gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location="rtsp://admin:hik12345@192.168.18.110:554/Streaming/Channels/101/" latency=500 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H265 ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! nvv4l2decoder ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080 ! xvimagesink

Comment: What gives `gst-discoverer-1.0 rtsp://admin:hik12345@192.168.18.110:554/Streaming/Channels/101/` ? Are you able to play it with gst-play-1.0 ? Or using uridecodebin element ?

Comment: Both of them also give same error NVPARSER: HEVC: Seeking is not performed on IRAP picture